# MVC 3 Entity Framework 4.1 get a list of unique data rows

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1. I need to return a view that has a list of rows of DISTINCT values from my Documents database table. In SQL Server, the query that works is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DocNum), Title, DocDate, DocFileName FROM Documents
```

How do I do the same thing in MVC 3?

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from d in cntx.Documents
            select d).Distinct();
```

Comment: This also results in the error The name cntx does not exist in the current context. I think this is because I used the entity framework 4.1?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var query = context.Documents.Select(x => new
                 {
                     x.DocNum,
                     x.Title,
                     x.DocDate,
                     x.DocFileName 
                 }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Distinct must go over all returned columns otherwise you could end up with single `DocNumber` and for example multiple dates and query engine wouldn't know which date to select because only one record with given `DocNumber` can be returned.

Comment: The get an error that says The name context does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I changed context.Documents to db.Documents and that compiled. Iget an error now that says The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`4[System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GUICE1.Models.Document]'.